# I am stuck on synchronizing scsi cache

Tags: 18.04

[output image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1geu75SJJ5AlVFxMu6p_YEw8eQx08u5A_/view?usp=drivesdk) because of low reputation not allowed to post image

I am installing 18.04 LTS in dual boot with Windows 10 and  this was after successful installation
I am installing the Ubuntu in hdd and have a ssd with win 10 installed.
I didn't install any Nvidia GPU driver this was just after I tried rebooting as shown by the installer
It's not a black screen it shows the some output

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: Boot with `nomodeset` and install the driver.

Comment: So should I force shutdown now ?

Comment: Yes, press Alt+SysRq and letters S, U, B sequentially. The system will reboot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Booting with `nomodeset`  then installing Nvidia drivers solves the problem